# Python Server capable of displaying an Image on a browser

Tags: python, image, http, header, http-headers

my question is simple and very straightforward. My server running wont display the image when I type localhost:9999/ok.jpg on the browser. I may be missing some concept of the server setup.

Here is the code:

```
import socket
import threading
import socketserver
import os

class MyHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):

def do_HEAD(self):
    self.send_response(200)
    self.send_header("Content-type", "image/jpg")
    self.end_headers()

def do_GET(self):
    self.send_response(200)
    self.send_header("Content-type", "image/jpg")
    self.end_headers() 
    f = open('ok.jpg', 'rb')
    self.wfile.write(f.read())
    f.close()


class MyServer(socketserver.ThreadingMixIn, socketserver.TCPServer):
    def __init__(self, server_adress, RequestHandlerClass):
        self.allow_reuse_address = True
        socketserver.TCPServer.__init__(self, server_adress, RequestHandlerClass, False)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    HOST, PORT = "localhost", 9999
    server = MyServer((HOST, PORT), MyHandler)
    server.server_bind()
    server.server_activate()
    server_thread = threading.Thread(target=server.serve_forever)
    server_thread.start()
```

Thank you for any possible help.

Comment: Maybe try adding a Content-Length header

Comment: Your `MyHandler` class doesn't override the default `RequestHandler.handle() ` method inherited from its base class (which does nothing).

Comment: @martineau can you elaborate on this ? I was using `def handle(self)` and thought I needed to change to do_HEAD and do_GET

Comment: I based my comment on [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socketserver.html?highlight=baserequesthandler#requesthandler-objects) and following exmple. To avoid having to define `RequestHandler.handle()` yourself and just provide `do_xxx()` methods, you should be deriving from class [`SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html?highlight=socketserver#module-SimpleHTTPServer).

Answer (score 1):

Judging from your do_GET and do_HEAD methods it looks like you really want `MyHandler` to extend `BaseHTTPRequestHandler`
http://docs.python.org/2/library/basehttpserver.html#BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler

The `BaseRequestHandler` does not know about HTTP (which is what your browser uses).

Comment: Isnt it `SimpleHTTPRequestHandler` to use `do_HEAD()` and `do_GET()`? I'm not sure which RequestHandler I have to extend/override to make it able to awnser a request displaying an image.

Comment: extends `BaseHTTPRequestHandler` and is used to serve files directly from the filesystem (relative to the working directory). `SimpleHTTPRequestHandler` implements `do_HEAD`and `do_GET` so you don't have to, and it may actually be more suitable to your problem if all you want to do is to get files from disk.

Answer (score 0):

Better use SimpleHTTPServer:

```
import SimpleHTTPServer
import SocketServer as socketserver
import os
import threading

class MyHandler(SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    path_to_image = 'ok.jpg'
    img = open(path_to_image, 'rb')
    statinfo = os.stat(path_to_image)
    img_size = statinfo.st_size
    print(img_size)

def do_HEAD(self):
    self.send_response(200)
    self.send_header("Content-type", "image/jpg")
    self.send_header("Content-length", img_size)
    self.end_headers()

def do_GET(self):
    self.send_response(200)
    self.send_header("Content-type", "image/jpg")
    self.send_header("Content-length", img_size)
    self.end_headers() 
    f = open(path_to_image, 'rb')
    self.wfile.write(f.read())
    f.close()         

class MyServer(socketserver.ThreadingMixIn, socketserver.TCPServer):
    def __init__(self, server_adress, RequestHandlerClass):
        self.allow_reuse_address = True
        socketserver.TCPServer.__init__(self, server_adress, RequestHandlerClass, False)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    HOST, PORT = "localhost", 9999
    server = MyServer((HOST, PORT), MyHandler)
    server.server_bind()
    server.server_activate()
    server_thread = threading.Thread(target=server.serve_forever)
    server_thread.start()
```